# Facebook new page for iphone app with download button

Tags: facebook, itunes-store

Hullo,
I have a number of facebook pages devoted to my published iOS apps and I would of course like users to be able to download the apps from them. Previously I managed the issue by having the apple page in the frame, but in the new Facebook page all those kind of features are all but disappeared and the button that once lead to the page takes instead to an empty Facebook page, as you may see at:
http://www.facebook.com/iPujaPro/
What should I do instead to allow the link to the app page in the AppStore when pressing the AppStore button?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

You can use this iframe app from woobox:

https://www.facebook.com/iframehost?sk=app_208195102528120